# Overriding public method in dynamically loaded class with AS3 and getDefinitionByName()

Tags: actionscript-3, dynamic, external

I have two SWFs: main.swf and external.swf.  main.swf needs to access some methods in external.swf, so it loads external.swf into itself and uses getDefinitionByName("package.Class") to access the class and one of its methods:

```
var ExternalClass = getDefinitionByName("package.Class") as Class;
var ClassInstance = new ExternalClass();
var NeededFunction:Function = ClassInstance["NeededFunction"] as Function;
var response:String = NeededFunction(param);
```

Now, I need to extend the functionality of NeededFunction (which is a public method)... I know it's possible to override public methods, but how would I go about this with a dynamically loaded class?

I was thinking I could do something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
var ClassInstance["NeededFunction"] = function(param1:uint):String { 
    var newString = "Your number is: "+param1.toString();  //New functionality
    return newString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to deal with this could be to have the classes in a package that's accessible by both SWFs. Just add the classes' root folder to your Actionscript path .

Instead of getting a class by using getDefinitionByName , you simply import it. As for overriding , you can create a Class that overrides one of the classes , or you can create an Interface.

```
import com.yourlocation.ExternalClass;

var external:ExternalClass = new ExternalClass();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to the SWF's classes or I would have done what you suggested long ago.  The method I need to extend is from a proprietary SWC library, so I can't modify the SWC unless I attempt to disassemble it, which I don't intend to do.

Comment: This article may help:
http://www.airtightinteractive.com/2009/06/better-flash-asset-loading-using-swcs/

Answer (score 0):

Using FlashDevelop this is pretty simple to fix.

Right click your included swc from the Project list.
Choose options then "include library (complete library)".

..you can now use getDefinitionByName to get a unreferenced class from your swc file.